# .htaccess redirection none extension to .html

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm doing a new version of my website. Google has crawled my website.
The url of all pages are written like this : http://www.domain.com/url-page

In my new version of my website, the url will be : http://www.domain.com/url-page.html

How do you do with the .htaccess the 301 redirection of all url without extension to .html please ?

But, the rule must not add .html to url if it's a directory (ended with /)

thanks you for your help

Comment: Perhaps you should read about .htaccess rewrite/redirect commands, try something, post your code here and then tell us where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\..+)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for your help. I've tested the code. But when it's a directory, i don't want that adds .html http://www.domain.com/url-page/ becomes http://www.domain.com/url-page/.html I don't want that changes.

Comment: I have changed the third line to : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\.*)$

Comment: Yes that is even better